# sqlite get total rows from group by

Tags: sql, sqlite

My table contains this data.

| c1 | c2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | No |
| A | No |
| A | Yes |
| A | Yes |
| A | Yes |
| B | No |
| B | No |
| B | No |
| B | Yes |

```
SELECT c1,c2,count(*) Nr FROM db GROUP BY c1,c2 ORDER BY c1,c2;
```

Give c1,c2,Nr columns
How to add a total column to output that give sum of Yes/No for A and B?

| c1 | c2 | Nr | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Yes | 3 | 5 |
| A | No | 2 | 5 |
| B | Yes | 1 | 4 |
| B | No | 3 | 4 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT c1, c2, count(*) as Nr,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY c1) as Total
FROM db
GROUP BY c1, c2
ORDER BY c1, c2;
```

Comment: This answer seems to have best performance from my tests.

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve your desired output:

```sql
SELECT db.c1, db.c2, count(*) Nr, db2.total
FROM db
LEFT JOIN (SELECT c1, count(*) total FROM db GROUP BY c1) db2
ON db.c1 = db2.c1
GROUP BY db.c1, db.c2 
ORDER BY db.c1, db.c2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT()` window function twice, without `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c1, c2) Nr,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c1) Total
FROM db
ORDER BY c1, c2;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3030bd04669e2b372051413b28f4e3cb).